# Is there a .profile-like file for use with MySQL Shell?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL.  I use MySQL Shell 1.0.9 on Windows 10.  Each time I log in, I have to issue a connect command (**\c localhost**), and supply the password.  Also, I have to issue a **\sql** command to switch out of the shell's default JavaScript mode.

Is there a mechanism where I can automate these per each log in, much like with a .profile file used on Linux for the Bash shell?